# What font will iOS choose for sans-serif?

Tags: ios, css, font-family

I'm very curious what font iOS actually chooses when setting `font-family: sans-serif`. I can't seem to find the answer anywhere, so I'm asking here.

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif; /* What font will iOS choose? */
}
```

Comment: It *should* fall back to Helvetica Neue, as I understand it. Can you post your code? Something doesn't sound quite right here.

Comment: I added the code for you. Your saying it _should_ fall back to Helvetica Neue; Is that what you experienced yourself or is it said by Apple to be the default behavior?

Comment: It was drawn from experience - as it turns out I was slightly incorrect, it's actually Helvetica (not Neue) :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default *sans-serif* font on iOS 6 and iOS 7 is *Helvetica*. I've set up a test with this CSS:

```
div.default {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

div.helvetica {
    font-family: 'Helvetica', serif;
}
```

The result is the very same. I also inspected it using the developer tools, to make sure the styles are applied correctly.

**iOS 6**

[image]

**iOS 7**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and putting so much effort in it by setting up a test!